# Capture values ​with anomalies

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture the `myserver` and `myserver-2` values, but I believe that the `-` of the value I want to capture is breaking my regex, any suggestions?

regex:

```
(.+:)?(.*)(:)
```

sample:

```
MSSQLSERVER:dba-myserver
MSSQLSERVER:myserver:MSS
MSSQLSERVER:dba-myserver:MSS
MSSQLSERVER:myserver-2:MSS
MSSQLSERVER:dba-myserver-2:MSS
MSSQLSERVER:myserver
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jvSjRU/1)

Comment: perhaps `(?:[^:]+:)(.*?)(?=:|$)`? https://regex101.com/r/jvSjRU/2

Comment: it is almost that, but it could not contain the `dba-`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/jvSjRU/3?

Comment: Is there anything I can put in place of `dba`? example `{3}`

Comment: You need to be more specific as to your question. If there could be any 3 character prefix, then use `.{3}`

Comment: Perfect, comment the answer, I will select, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of something. If you've got a working solution I'm happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
^[^:]+:(?:[^-]{3}-)?([^:]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OmWAdx/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^:]+` - one or more chars other than a `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `(?:[^-]{3}-)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching any three chars other than a `-` and then a `-`
- `([^:]*)` - Capturing group 1: any zero or more chars other than a `:`.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%5E%3A%5D%2B%3A(%3F%3A%5B%5E-%5D%7B3%7D-)%3F(%5B%5E%3A%5D*)):

[image]

Comment: do you think it is possible to capture the two patterns that i added the most?

Comment: `myserver:LZ` and `MSS-myserver:LZ`

Comment: If so, I would have a single regex for everything, LOL

Comment: @LuisHenrique You'd have to precise the pattern a bit, an example is `^(?:MSSQLSERVER:)?(?:[^-]{3}-)?([^:]*)`, see [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/OmWAdx/3).